# Finite colength ideals in a power series ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

$\newcommand{\Hilb}{\operatorname{Hilb}}$Let $I\subset R:=\mathbb{C}[[x,y]]$ be an ideal. Then, $I$ is said to be of colength $n$ if $\dim_\mathbb{C}(R/I) = n$. For example the ideal $(x,y)$ has colength 1 since $R/(x,y)\cong \mathbb{C}$.

Now, let's denote by $\Hilb^n:=\{I$ is an ideal of colength $n \}$. (These are in fact the punctual Hilbert schemes of length $n$ ideals supported at a (fixed) smooth point of a surface, and has a natural scheme structure).

$\Hilb^n$ for small values of $n$ can be computed by brute force. For example:
$\Hilb^0 = \{R\}$; $\Hilb^1 = \{(x,y)\}$, $\Hilb^2 = \{(x^2,y), (x,y^2)\}\cup \{(x+\lambda y,xy)\mid \lambda\in \mathbb{C}^\times\}$ (we can see that $\Hilb^2$ "looks like" $\mathbb{P}^1$).

Now, define $m:\coprod_n \Hilb^n\to \mathbb{N}$ by defining $m(I)$ to be the minimal number of generators for $I$. Equivalently, $m(I) = \dim_\mathbb{C}(I/(x,y)I)$.

I would like to know if there is an explicit description of the strata $\Hilb^n_m:= \{I\in \Hilb^n\mid m(I) = m\}$.

For example, $\Hilb^3$ consists of ideals $(x^3,y), (x^2,xy,y^2), (x,y^3)$ and $(x^2+\lambda y,xy), (y^2+\lambda x, xy)$ for $\lambda\in \mathbb{C}^\times$. (Is this correct/are these all of them?). Hence, in the Grothendieck ring of varieties over $\mathbb{C}$, we have the following equality: $$[\Hilb^3_2] = [pt] + [pt] + [\mathbb{C}^\times] + [\mathbb{C}^\times] = 2[\mathbb{C}]$$ And $[\Hilb^3_3]= [pt]$.

I can write these out explicitly for low values of $n$ but I can't seem to find a way to describe $[\Hilb^n_m]$ in general. I read a few papers, including Iarrobino's "Punctual Hilbert Schemes" but could not find exactly what I am looking for. Any references or insights will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: With your notation, $\mathrm{Hilb}^1$ is a single point, $\mathrm{Hilb}^2$ is the projective line. In general $\mathrm{Hilb}^n$ is of dimension $n-1$, so your description for $n=3$ seems wrong, since it looks like dimension one in your description. You may find some themes in this direction in Granger's thesis (which is published), though it is in French.